# PHP multidimensional array and adding data as fast as possible

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using PHP to add data to a multidimensional array. I have two ways which I have been using. They should do the same job.

If I do this 1000 times in a row, which one is faster and recommended?

A)

```
$a[$arr['ka']][$arr['mu']][$arr['kd']]['p'] = $p;
$a[$arr['ka']][$arr['mu']][$arr['kd']]['k'] = $k;
```

B)

```
$a[$arr['ka']][$arr['mu']][$arr['kd']] = ["p" => $p, "k" => $k];
```

Comment: Benchmark it…?!

Comment: Why don't you simple try and measure?

Comment: And frankly: why should that difference matter? Adding elements to an array _inside_ a running script cannot be of significant importance _per definition_. This would only be of interest if persistent data were to be manipulated in bigger scale. But for that certainly no in-memory-array would be the approach of choice...

Answer (score 0):

```
$a[$arr['ka']][$arr['mu']][$arr['kd']] = ["p" => $p, "k" => $k];
```

This one will be faster than the first one.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate on that statement? Or is it just god given insight?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to hear the reason.